# Updating state after timeout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a very rudimentary application that displays information about the provided URL

```
<!-- template -->
<input id=url data-bind="value: setUrl, value: url">
<div class=url-pieces data-bind="foreach: pieces">
    <h2 class=url-piece data-bind="
        text: name,
        css: { 'slide-in': $root.isValidUrl() && url() && canSlideIn() },
        style: {'transition-delay': delay}"></h2>
</div>
```

In the ViewModel, I have

```
self.setUrl = ko.computed(function () {
    var reverse = false;
    self.url($("#url").val());
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.pieces(), function (piece) {
        piece.delay(self.delay + 'ms');
        self.delay += 200;
    });
    self.delay = 0;
});
```

`setUrl` is called whenever the input value changes, and this updates the delay for each of `pieces` (which is an `observableArray`).

What I would like to do is only increase the delay for each element if its visibility state is not changing.

That is, when `setUrl` is called, if the element for the piece already had `.slide-in` or already didn't have `.slide-in` compared to the previous value, it should not increase the delay.

The problem is I have no idea how to track this state and compare it to whatever it was before.  This could be done with an `observable` on `UrlPiece`, but I'm simply not sure how to trigger/record state changes.

[**I have created a working fiddle with my code.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/3nWKD/1/)

You can see the problem if you type `http://example.com` (scheme/host/path appear).  Then, if you add `?foo`, *query* will appear, but it takes 800ms (600 from the visible ones, and 200 from *port*, which is still not visible).  In fact there should be no delay because none of scheme/host/path/port changed state, but I don't know what trigger can record that or how to check it after the fact.

Any other suggestions for improving this code especially in the spirit of Knockout are welcome.  I think that `UrlsViewModel.isValidUrl` is wrong, and passing the observable `url` to each `UrlPiece` also seems wrong to me.

Comment: I think you will have to internally maintain the state of each piece you have already processed. Or if you are applying the delay to wait for the user to finish typing, you could try http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html